# how to convert excel cell values into an array

Tags: excel, powershell

I am creating a script that will gather cell data from excel and input it into a variable. I could then manipulate the data from there. Where I having the issue is I am unable to take that variable of cell values and break it into there own values. Essentially i am taking the data from the excel file and manipulating it to export the information to another excel file. I am using or at least attempting to use the module PSExcel

```
$objExcel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application

$excel = Open-ExcelPackage -Path ".\test.xlsx"

$worksheet = $excel.Workbook.Worksheets['worksheet name']


$source = $worksheet.Cells['Y12:y226'].value
#$destination = $worksheet.Cells['Z12:Z226'].value
```

Comment: Can you include what the cell data looks like in your question body?

Comment: Look into the Import-Excel module, it is much easier than trying to work with COM objects https://github.com/dfinke/ImportExcel

Answer (score 0):

@AutomatedOrder has it right, the [ImportExcel](https://github.com/dfinke/ImportExcel) module is the way to go. It works similarly to the native Import-CSV/Export-CSV in Powershell for simple things and for the type of data manipulation you're trying to do it's way easier than the COM objects.